# how to import Cesium source to use

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

The example of cesium official website is to import cesium.js under the `./build` folder, so I can't see the execution of the Cesium internal Source code. If I want to import the source code under the `./Source` file to use, how should I import it?

I directly import./Source/Cesium, throw error,`Cannot use import statement outside a module`,and `Cesium is not defined`

Comment: I think, this question is more related to ESM/CommonJS interoperability rather than CesiumJS

Answer (score 0):

To "import" Cesium source as ESM, do:

import * as Cesium from './Cesium/Build/CesiumUnminified/index.js';

https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium/blob/main/Documentation/Contributors/BuildGuide/README.md#build-output